# How to correlate count variables that are nested / non-independent?

Tags: correlation, count-data, independence, nested-data

[image: stuff]

Above is a snapshot of a subset of a larger dataset, N=61.

- `Group` is the group number,
- `Iterations` is indicating the iteration number for every group,
- `TradeoffTalk` is the frequency count of a certain 'level of discussion' by the group for every iteration ('level of discussion' is an ordinal variable but *not* used directly here),
- `IDRef` is the frequency count of a certain 'action' by the group for every iteration ('action' is a nominal variable but *not* used directly here),
- `ProcPrompt` is the frequency count of certain 'instruction' ('instruction' is a nominal variable but *not* used directly here) given to the group during the iteration

Can I treat `TradeoffTalk`, `IDRef` and `ProcPrompt` as continuous variables and run Pearson's correlation and partial correlation between them? I am trying to find if these are related and describe the relationship (positive / negative) between them. For example, one claim I'd like to make is, there is a strong positive relationship between `TradeoffTalk` and `IDRef` (enough to indicate significant relationship, causal claim is *not* needed).

Comment: You have many rows with the same `Group` ID; are the rows independent?

Comment: @gung- Every iteration is unique even if it belongs to the same group. (sorry, I'm fairly new to stats so let me know if this doesn't answer your question)

Comment: The iterations may be unique, but you have multiple observations from the each group w/ many different groups, right? That would make the observation non-independent.

Comment: yes, I do have multiple observations from each group with many different groups. What would be the right way to analyze this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a problem with your correlating count variables.  (Whether this will adequately correspond to your substantive question is another matter, and one that I cannot evaluate.)  The *test* of your correlation can be invalidated if you mostly have $0$ counts and a few high values, so you should bear that in mind.  The issue with the nesting is that correlating two variables while ignoring the groups will conflate two different aspects of the data: how variable x is associated with y *within* groups, and the variations *between* groups.  This is almost certainly not what you want.  I strongly suspect your question has to do with how x is related to y within groups.  A quick and dirty way to deal with this might be to mean center each variable within each group, then you could get a correlation.

Comment: Thanks @gung for your suggestion. I will try to run the correlation using the means. I do have a lot of 0 counts and few very high values (and other numbers in between). I am also interested in variations between the groups. Since correlations will not serve that purpose, what other options do I have to describe what's going on in the data?

Comment: Don't correlate using the *means*, correlate the *de-meaned* data.